# Excel - Revocation information for the security certificate for this site is not available

Tags: excel, certificate, ssl-certificate, certificate-revocation

I am opening a XLS file over https (which runs over TLS 1.1). While opening file, I am getting error "Revocation information for the security certificate for this site is not available".

[image]

If i uncheck "Internet Explorer -> Tools > Internet Options -> Advanced -> Security -> Check for server certificate revocation" option then I am able to open XLS file over http in excel.

But this will set this setting only for my user not for other users. Other users still face this issue.

In website certificate, CRL Distribution Point -> Distribution Point Name ->          Full Name URL=http://ss.symcb.com/ss.crl". CRL distribution point URL is not reachable as there is no internet connectivity on the server.

Please suggest how to fix this issue for all the user.

OS : Windows 2012 R2

Office : Office Profession Plus 2016

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by configuring the system wide group policy to disable certificate revocation check for all users.

```
Run > gpedit.msc -> Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Internet Control Panel > Advanced Page > Check for server certificate revocation > Disable
```